# How to print all Roles that are granted access to a Node in TPL?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

Anyone know how to display Roles that are granted access to a node in a node TPL in D7?
IE: Admin, Editor, Food Snobs:

I have already tried [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and Devel node access, yet there is no info.

I am using the [Nodeaccess](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module to grant access to Roles and I want to display all the Roles that have access on the page so my users don't share a link with someone that doesn't have access to see the link.